# Markupsafe stopping cookiecutter from installing

Tags: python, pip

When trying to install cookiecutter in a virtualenv with python 3.8 I keep coming up against the following error.
I get the same error when trying to install jinja2 or markupsafe directly.
It seems that cookiecutter is dependent on jinja2 which is dependent on markupsafe.

```
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe'

    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of MarkupSafe
Command "/home/jhylands/Documents/duplicates/py/bin/python3.8 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lcltnqyr/markupsafe/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ykckm_bz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jhylands/Documents/duplicates/py/include/site/python3.8/markupsafe" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lcltnqyr/markupsafe/
```

Answer (score 0):

After having tried setting the version manually of markupsafe to 1.1.1
as suggested here[1] I ended up solving (getting around) the issue by installing version 2 of markupsafe.

It seems that jinja2 requires a minimum of version 2 and that althoough there seems to be an issue with the most up to date version of markupsafe, version 2 installs correctly.

```
pip install markupsafe==2
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can try installing the 'markupsafe' module manually using pip

```
**python -m pip install --upgrade pip**
```

and then

```
**python -m pip install --upgrade pip**
```